# Combine search bar and address bar of webview- android

Tags: android, url, webview

i have a webview with a url field but i have                       to type the full     url to open a website (http:// and domain), so is there a way to make the url bar function like     a search bar?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
private EditText urlEditText;
private ProgressBar progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());


    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);//Enable Cookies


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//Enable Java Script
    webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/"); //Set Home page
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);//Remove ScrollBars
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(12);//Set Font Size
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);//Enable Image Loading
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);//Enable Flash
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);//Transparent Screen When Loading
  //webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//Set Zoom Controls 

    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);//Set Cache (8mb)
    String appCachePath =           getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();//Set Cache (8mb)
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);//Set Cache (8mb)
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);//Set Cache (8mb)
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);//Set Cache (8mb)
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);//Set Cache (8mb)





    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setMax(100);

    Button openUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    openUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String url = urlEditText.getText().toString();
            if (validateUrl(url)) {
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl(url);

                MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            }
        }

        private boolean validateUrl(String url) {
            return true;
        }
    });

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {         
        MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);       



 }
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{


webview.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
}
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {

     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack())

    {
webView.goBack();
    return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did. I put it into a method that listens to when the keyboard enter button gets clicked. Add as many top-level domains as you need. Replace the contents of the

```
if (validateUrl(url)) {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

method with this:

```
if (edittext.getText().toString().contains("http://")
        || edittext.getText().toString()
                .contains("https://")) {
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(),
            0);
    return true;
    } else if (edittext.getText().toString().contains(".com")
        || edittext.getText().toString().contains(".net")
        || edittext.getText().toString().contains(".org")
        || edittext.getText().toString().contains(".gov")) {
    webView.loadUrl("http://"
            + url);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(),
            0);
    return true;
    } else {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q="
            + url);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(),
            0);
}
```